# Laravel is not sending emails even configuration is right

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp, laravel-mail

I am trying to send emails in laravel and whenever I try to send the mail it gives me this error.

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@vexpo.pk" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.0 Invalid login or password ". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response

I have tried many solutions and tried many answers from here but nothing is working here are the config I am using.

**.Env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.vexpo.pk
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@vexpo.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**Mail.php**

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.vexpo.pk'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@vexpo.pk'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Naeem Saqib'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'info@vexpo.pk',

'password' => '******',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

**Method I am using in controller**

```
Mail::to('user@example.com')->send(new MailNotify());
```

And here is my mailable class

**MailNotify.php**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.email');
}
```

I am stuck now and no solution is working for me please help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is controller

Comment: Why MAIL_ENCRYPTION is null ? I think it should be tls

Comment: I am using this method `Mail::to('user@example.com')->send(new MailNotify());`

Comment: @SagarGautam I was using tls before

Comment: check out this laravel post. [How to send emails in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476577/how-send-email-in-laravel-5-8/56477002#56477002)

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the mail server than with Laravel. Your settings seem correct. The error also clearly states it expects another response from the mail server. Please check with your mail server host that all the configuration is set correctly.

Comment: based on error code returned, it's a problem within the mail server, not laravel problem,
check the mail server configuration

Comment: I am checking my server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MAIL_USERNAME=info@vexpo.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=******



all problems are here... you should check in your vexpo account they provide username & password . 

ex

MAIL_USERNAME=281c53efc0089w
MAIL_PASSWORD=8fe2dd1b8b975q

Like This. not your mail id


I solved my this type problem. on this way.

i hope it will worked
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been using titan email and was facing the same issue, and the best answer on this thread did not work, but I researched a bit more and turns out if your mail password contains special characters you need to place them in quotes like these 'p@ssw0rd', this worked for me as I was also getting the exact same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).